# minimum window subsequence leetcode dynamic programming solution

Tags: python, algorithm, strings, dynamic-programming

> Given strings `S` and `T`, find the minimum (contiguous) substring `W`
>   of `S`, so that `T` is a subsequence of `W`.
>
> If there is no such window in `S` that covers all characters in `T`,
>   return the empty string "". If there are multiple such minimum-length
>   windows, return the one with the left-most starting index.

**Solution:**

Concept is almost inspired from \$O(N log N)\$ solution for longest increasing sequence in a integer array presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631726/how-to-determine-the-longest-increasing-subsequence-using-dynamic-programming).
Let `DP[i]` represent longest increasing sequence in `T` which matches `[0:i]` subsequence of `S`. So,

```
DP[j] = i if S[j] == T[i] and j == 0

DP[j] = DP[j-1] if S[j] == T[i]
```

And then we are looking for `DP[len(T)-1]`.

```
class Solution:
    def minWindow(self, S, T):
        """
        :type S: str
        :type T: str
        :rtype: str
        """
        dp = [-1] * (len(T)+1)
        dic = {}
        for i, t in enumerate(T):
            dic.setdefault(t, []).append(i)
        global_index, starting_index, global_count = -1, -1, 1 << 31
        for i in range(len(S)):
            if S[i] in dic:
                for j in dic[S[i]][::-1]:
                    if j == 0:
                        dp[j] = i
                    else:
                        dp[j] = dp[j-1]
                if dp[len(T)-1] != -1 and (i - dp[len(T)-1] + 1) < global_count:
                    starting_index, global_count = dp[len(T)-1], i - dp[len(T)-1] + 1
        if starting_index == -1:
            return ""
        return S[starting_index:starting_index + global_count]
```